# Сильно ли будит нагружен мой проект таким кодом?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сильно ли пострадает оптимизация от такого кода?

```
public static DateTime EventTime_DoPlayers = DateTime.Now;

public void Update() {
    if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(EventTime_DoPlayers).TotalMilliseconds > 1000) {
        Events.EventTime_DoPlayers = DateTime.Now;
        Thread doPlayersThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoPlayers));
        doPlayersThread.IsBackground = true;
        doPlayersThread.Start();
    }
}

public static void DoPlayers() {
    //Проверки (Cooldown вычисления, Premium date check и тд)
}
```

Возможно если какие нибудь альтернативы?Framework 3.5!

Пример!

```
foreach(UserData userData in Users.All) {
    NetUser netUser = NetUser.FindByUserID(userData.SteamID);
    if (netUser != null && !netUser.did_join) netUser = null;
    List < Countdown > RemoveCountdown = new List < Countdown > ();
    foreach(Countdown CD in Users.CountdownList(userData.SteamID)) if (CD.Expires) {
        if (CD.Expired) {
            RemoveCountdown.Add(CD);
            continue;
        }
        if (CD.Command.Equals("pvp", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && userData.HasFlag(UserFlags.nopvp)) {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(CD.TimeLeft) < Core.CommandNoPVPCountdown) {
                userData.SetFlag(UserFlags.nopvp, false);
                if (netUser != null) Broadcast.Notice(netUser, "☢", Config.GetMessage("Command.PvP.Enabled", netUser));
                Broadcast.NoticeAll("☢", Config.GetMessage("Command.PvP.NoticeEnabled", null, userData.Username), netUser);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Смотрите, допустим речь идет о 60 fps. Таким образом ваш код будет 60 раз в секунду запускать новый поток и что-то там делать. И так без каких-либо ограничений. Вы уверены, что вам это надо?

Comment: @vmchar Что тогда можете посоветовать?

Comment: В основном подумать на архитектурой и обосновать для себя необходимость столь частого вычисления однотипной функции. Сложно что-то сказать, не зная зачем оно вам

Comment: @vmchar для вычиследний все нужно - например если у игрока истекло время блокировки команды в чате то удалять ее из листа

Comment: @vmchar я добавил пример в вопросе

Comment: В целом подход для разгрузки main thread`а неплохой, но лучше использовать встроенную Job System. Таким образом и асинхронно можно что-то делать, но и при этом Unity сама заботиться о потоках - ничего вручную делать не требуется.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker у меня старая версия unity 4.5.5 и в ней нету jobs насколько я знаю.Переходить на новую нету возможности так как работаю с готовым проектом, патчив его под свои нужды через dnspy

Comment: Ну тогда если действительно есть необходимость что-то делать асинхронно - делайте хотя бы пул потоков, либо аналог job потока, настолько часто создавать потоки - дело гиблое.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker то что я выложил - всего лишь пример.В основном у меня такие проверки if (Helper.Full_Initialized && UsersManager.All() != null && !_EventComponent.DoPlayersBool &&
                DateTime.Now.Subtract(EventTime_DoPlayers).TotalMilliseconds > 1000).Что за пул потоков?Может вы можете предложить примерный код

Comment: Ну если вы совершаете какое-то действие очень редко, все проверки производите в main thread'е, то в принципе можно и новый поток создавать каждый раз. Вопрос не о пуле потоков - ищите здесь или на англоязычном SO "thread pool".

Comment: @RiotBr3aker спасибо буду смотреть )